# RegEX : Find match based on condition

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to RegEx and looking for a solution to this condition. I am writing my code in C# and don't want to use any STRING functions.

Below is a sample string that I get:

```
610WBDFGFGM0122544
```

Now the condition I need to check is,

```
If string starts with "6" && 6th character is "D"
```

Can anyone tell me how to write RegEx for the above condition?

Comment: Why in the world do you not want you use simple string functions?

Comment: `str[0]==X && str[6]==Y`

Comment: you can accomplish this doing several things.. `string.Contains, string.SubString, ect...` this is not that trivial.. here is a good link to use as well until you become more proficient with .net language and functions that are available to you especially using the `String Class` [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) [MSDN String.StartsWith Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @EZI shouldn't that second index be 5?

Comment: @juharr do you think it is important. I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^6.{4}D
```

Here, `^` is the start of the string, `.{4}` means any four characters.

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wD5rG8/2)